# how to change theme in Magento2

Tags: magento, themes, admin, magento2

UPDATE: this could be a version issue, should I update to the non-stable 2.0.4?

I know this should seem obvious to someone, but clearly it's not.
as state in the documentation

> In Admin, go to Stores > Configuration > Design.

but there is only a robot txt edit as seen in the below screen shot

[image: design tab showing only robot .txt editor]

I track down the issue on github [#4251](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4251)

> All design configurations were moved to Content -> Design -> Configuration

when I get there, my custom theme successfully show up, but no button to change it, as seen below. there is no option to change from the default Luma theme to blank theme neither.

[image]

is it just me? or I am blind and missing something really obvious?
My Magento version is 2.0.0.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In newer version of Magento all design related item moved to :
Content-> Design -> Configuration -> Edit

Answer (score 0):

have you tried in ssh:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade –keep-generated
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: I am in the process of upgrading is 2.0.6, I will try your method if that fail too.

Answer (score 0):

You can change theme in Content => Configuration => Edit option( in grid records)

Answer (score 0):

The default theme in Magento 2 is called Magento Blank. To activate it, follow these steps:

1- Login into your admin panel and navigate to Stores->Settings ->Configuration section.

2- In the General tab press Design.

3- Select Magento Blank among the list of available themes in Design Theme option press the Save Config button in the top right.

4- Refresh the Magento cache.

5- Check how the new theme appears on the site frontend.

For pictorial or video representation go to the URL: https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-2-x-switch-store-default-theme.html

Answer (score 0):

**Admin panel => Content => Design => Configuration => Edit => Applied Theme**